# React Router Dom v6 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'path' of 'match' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a problem after switching from React Router Dom v5 to v6.

I encounter this error that I can't solve.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'path' of 'match' as
> it is undefined.

Here is what my `app.jsx` looks like

```js
...
import { Home } from "home";
import { Listings } from "listings";
import { Navigate, Route, Routes, unstable_HistoryRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
...
import { history } from "_helpers";

export function App() {
  // const auth = useRecoilValue(authAtom);
  
  return (
    <WrapperPage>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Nav />
        <Alert />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/browse" element={<Listings />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<Navigate from="*" to="/" />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </WrapperPage>
  );
```

and my `listings.jsx`

```js
import React from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { WrapperPage } from "_components/pages";
import { List } from "./List";
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";

export function Listings({ match }) {
  const { path } = match;

  return (
    <WrapperPage className={`${styles.listing} py-5 px-md-5 px-sm-3`}>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path={path} element={<List />} />
        {/* <Route path={`${path}/add`} component={AddEdit} /> */}
      </Routes>
    </WrapperPage>
  );
}
```

Error occurs when changing page from `'/'` to `'/browse'` (listings)

Comment: Did you read the [upgrade documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/reach)? Lots of info about `match` and `useMatch` in there.

Comment: v6 does not anymore need the exact prop, and it doesn't pass anymore params, match, etc... through props, so you'll have to use the hooks they expose.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below procedure to migrate from React Router Dom v5 to v6.

First of all, remove the current version of react router dom from dev dependencies,

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0"
  }
```

For that delete,

```
"react-router-dom": "^5.3.0"
```

Install react router dom v6.

```
npm i -D react-router-dom@6.3.0
```

Now your devDependencies should be like,

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"
  }
```

Use the below code to apply react router dom v6,

**App.js**

```
import { Home } from "./home";
import { Listings } from "./listings";
import {
  Navigate,
  Route,
  Routes,
  BrowserRouter as Router
} from "react-router-dom";

export function App() {
  // const auth = useRecoilValue(authAtom);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/browse" element={<Listings />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate from="*" to="/" />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**home.jsx**

```
export function Home() {
    return <h1>Hello, Home</h1>;
}
```

**listing.jsx**

```
export function Listings(props) {
    return <h1>Hello, Listing</h1>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `useMatch` for `react-router-dom` 6, read the doc for more info: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/reach#usematch